# why in JDK 7, useing try-with-resources feature can close file automatically?

Tags: java

When I reading this [Java IO tutorials](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-file-from-java-bufferedreader-example/), the try-with-resources will not need to call the close() to close file. Why?

In the first example, it invokes the close() method in finally

```
package com.mkyong.io;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class BufferedReaderExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        BufferedReader br = null;

        try {

            String sCurrentLine;

            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\testing.txt"));

            while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(sCurrentLine);
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (br != null)br.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

But in the 2nd example, it doesn't invoke the close() method and it still works. Why?

```
package com.mkyong.io;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class BufferedReaderExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\testing.txt")))
        {

            String sCurrentLine;

            while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(sCurrentLine);
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 

    }
}
```

Comment: Because the streams implement the `AutoClosable` interface...it's a language level specification

Comment: @MadProgrammer for the try-with-recourse they have to implement `java.lang.AutoCloseable`

Comment: @SubOptimal It was something like that ;P

Comment: Have you tried to read the documentation about the [try-with-resources statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)? It doesn't seems so.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because Java handles the closing for you.

> The try-with-resources statement is a try statement that declares one or more resources. A resource is an object that must be closed after the program is finished with it. The try-with-resources statement ensures that each resource is closed at the end of the statement. Any object that implements java.lang.AutoCloseable, which includes all objects which implement java.io.Closeable, can be used as a resource.

(http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)

Answer (score 3):

Its a feature in java 7 which will close all the resource you used with try(...) irrespective of whether  the try block executed successfully or not. before java 7 we had to use the finally block if we needed this feature.

Comment: I don't think the resources will be closed if you call System.exit in the try block, but I might be wrong.

Comment: @Puce you are right !!!. i tested it and found it wont be close in that case. Corrected my answer, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

From Oracle documentation:

> The try-with-resources statement is a try statement that declares one
>   or more resources. A resource is an object that must be closed after
>   the program is finished with it. The try-with-resources statement
>   ensures that each resource is closed at the end of the statement.

[Please refer Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try With Resource is Simply reduce the overhead of finally block. In try() you can define different different Resources which you need in Try block. and Try With Resource block ensures that resource will be closed at the end of execution of try block.

Basically all the resources which implements AutoCloseable interface, those resource can be closed automatically by JVM.you can check description of [Close method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html#close()) in Java Docs as well.